# Increment Number X Amount of Times (and Print)

Tags: php

I am working on a booking `form` which once a date is selected, the available times are shown. I am having a problem with hiding some of the available times from a drop down box and would like some help.

Currently, I can successfully hide an available time if there is a booking with this start time on the same day. For example:

> Bookings can be made from 10:00 until 16:00. If there is a booking at
>   11:00 for 1 hour, the following times will be shown in the drop down box:
>   
> 10:00
>   
> 12:00
>   
> 13:00
>   
> 14:00
>   
> 15:00
>   
> 16:00

My problem now is for bookings greater than 1 hour. I want to hide the available times if there is a 2 hour booking. For example:

> A Booking is made at 11:00 for 2 hours. This will remove 11:00 and
>   12:00 from the available times. The following times will be shown in the drop down box:
>   
> 10:00
>   
> 13:00
>   
> 14:00
>   
> 15:00
>   
> 16:00

What is the best way to achieve this? I am currently storing the start time & total hours in a database and was curious if a loop would be possible to add 1 hour to the start time until it reaches the same amount of total hours.

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question showing what you have so far.

Comment: If you can remove a single availability time when there is a one-hour booking, how is it possible you can't remove 2, 3 or 10 availability times when there is a 2, 3 or 10-hours booking? How is it different?

Comment: Without seeing what your code looks like now or your data structure it is very hard to give an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much of your code or data structure this is the best I can do for you

```
<?php

//these would be the appointments stored on the DB
$results = array(
    array(
        'apt_date' => '2016-06-01',
        'apt_time' => '10',
        'apt_duration' => 2
    ), array(
        'apt_date' => '2016-06-01',
        'apt_time' => '14',
        'apt_duration' => 1
    )
);

for ($i = 10; $i <= 16; $i++) {
    $ok = true;
    foreach ($results as $item) {
        if (($i == $item['apt_time'])) {
            $ok = false;
           if($item['apt_duration'] > 1){
            $i = $i +$item['apt_duration'];
           }
        }
    }
    if($ok){
        echo $i . ':00';
        echo '</br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I dont think this is what I'm looking for. I have edited the main post to help make it more clear.

Comment: Ok can you share how this data is stored in your DB so I can change my answer?

Comment: Or the code that you currently have to hide one hour.

Comment: I actually modified this quite a bit and got it to somewhat work to what I want apart from one thing. Thank you very much @ecorvo !